# How can I return and parse document returned from the Firebase server to the client?

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Foreword: I'm an iOS programmer diving into Node/JS. I created a `https.onCall` function as I need to perform multiple reads + writes. In the final update promise, I'd ideally like to return the data in a form that could be decoded into a `DocumentSnapshot` (as this is easily converted into a model), but I'm happy to just do what best practice is as well.

This is what the relevant piece of code looks like:

```
return group.ref.set({
  members: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user)
}, { merge: true }).then(result => {
   // The additional `get` seems necessary because the completion block doesn't contain the updated document's data
   return group.ref.get().then(doc => {
     return doc
  })
})
```

I also tried returning `return group.ref.get()`, but both failed to parse on the iOS side:

```
// This fails to cast
guard let document = result?.data as? DocumentSnapshot else { return }
```

I was thinking this would be an alternative I can make work:

```
...
return {
  id: doc.id,
  data: doc.data()
}
```

And then manually decoding the JSON on the iOS side. But this feels very heavy-handed, and so I'm hoping someone can illuminate me with a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable functions do not receive or deliver strongly typed data.  Everything is boiled down to JSON, which is converted to the relevant low-level types on either end.

If you want to deliver a DocumentSnapshot from a callable function, you should minimally call its `data()` method to get a plain JavaScript object that is easily serialized, which is what your alternative is doing just fine.  Personally, I don't see this as "heavy-handed".  This is very typical data exchange between systems that don't share a sophisticated type serialization system.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the validation this is the right approach. Re heavy-handed: considering there are methods to get a document with a given reference, and using said document to easily initialize your own custom object, I was curious if there was a way to hook into those decoding methods. Worst case I can take a look at the source and implement a wrapper around my http request though. Appreciate your speedy reply!

Comment: For posterity, I did find a Firebase method exists to decode objects that can be reused: `Firestore.Decoder().decode(Model.self, from: data)`